# Bootstrap 3 .navbar-toggle toggled state

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, mobile, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I'm using bootstrap 3.0 and working on a mobile site.  I'm trying to figure out how to change the background colour of the button.navbar-toggle when the navbar has collapsed.

Basically what I'm asking is how to show a 'pressed' state on mobile device when the navbar menu is opened?

Answer (score 9):

Try by adding this style after your bootstrap style-sheet.

```
<style>
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
  border-color: #563D7C;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
  background-color: #563D7C;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle,
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
background-color: #c0d730;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't like the styling by `:hover`, because there is no `:hover` on mobile devices.
Also the `:focus` style would not be optimal, because when you close the navigation by clicking on the toggle, the `:focus` will stay on the toggle, but the user does not interact with the navigation anymore. So that makes not much sense.

I prefere to set a class on the toggle button by JavaScript. Bootstrap has events to catch the collaping.

```
$('#myNavigation')
   .on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
     $('#myNavigationToggle').addClass('active')
   })
   .on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
     $('#myNavigationToggle').removeClass('active')
   });
```

Documentation: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-events